# How to pass parameters to default camera app while launching for result

Tags: android, camera

I need to navigate to device camera app from my app and get result back from it. I have already added code for it and it is working as well, but there are few things I want to achieve to complete the module.

- Pass a value for zoom level from my app to camera app and set that as zoom there.
- Camera app is showing its own preview screen, which I don't want as my app already has a preview screen with some custom controls.

I have gone through so many blogs/sites to see how can I customise this but couldn't find any solution. Pasted below is my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
@Composable
fun OpenDeviceCamera(
viewModel: PhotoViewModel,
navController: DestinationsNavigator,
analytics: AnalyticsManager?
) {
val context = LocalContext.current
label.let { label ->
    if (viewModel.showDeviceCam.value) {
        val file = getPhotoFile(context)
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file
        );

        var capturedImageUri by remember {
            mutableStateOf<Uri>(Uri.EMPTY)
        }

        val cameraLauncher =
            rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { isSuccess ->
                if (isSuccess) {
                    capturedImageUri = uri
                    showPreviewOfImage(navController, analytics, uri.toString(), viewModel)
                }
             
            }
        SideEffect {
            cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the things that you are seeking are part of the `TakePicture` (`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`) protocol. There are hundreds upon hundreds of camera apps that could be launched, and none have to even offer undocumented support for what you want.

`TakePicture` / `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` are only suitable for cases where you need zero control over the picture-taking process, including whether or not it actually works (camera apps are buggy).

If you need your desired level of control, use CameraX or another camera library and implement the functionality in your own app.

Comment: I am already suing CameraX in my app, but observed that while zoom in Camerax/Camera2 is unable to access the telephoto lens of device which results in a low quality image. Due to this decided to navigate to device camera only on 2.0 or above zoom levels. So when user navigates to default camera app, i want to preset the selected zoom in camera as user has already selected a zoom level in my app.

Comment: @Droid: That is not an option, sorry.